# Cannot find getContext() as per Android dedicated device documentation

Tags: android, android-studio

I know a similar question has been asked several times before but I have been through those and they do not help me.
I am trying to set up a Samsung Tab A (Android 8.1) as a single-use device. I have already written the app which works perfectly but as the device will be used by the public I need to lock it down into kiosk mode.
I am trying to follow the developer guide at the link below but immediately hit problems.
https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode

So first thing I try to do is whitelist the app as per the example given:

```
// Whitelist two apps.
private static final String KIOSK_PACKAGE = "com.example.kiosk";
private static final String PLAYER_PACKAGE = "com.example.player";
private static final String[] APP_PACKAGES = {KIOSK_PACKAGE, PLAYER_PACKAGE};

// ...

Context context = getContext();
DevicePolicyManager dpm =
    (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
ComponentName adminName = getComponentName(context);
dpm.setLockTaskPackages(adminName, APP_PACKAGES);
```

The documentation is not clear on where this code should go but I have put it in an override for `onResume()`.

I am using auto-import in Android Studio but it tells me that `getContext()` cannot be found. I have tried changing to `getApplicationContext()` and just using `this` as suggested elsewhere but then it complains that `getComponentName()` should not have any parameters. I have tried simply removing the context parameter, using `context.getComponentName()` and also using no context variables.   These compile but the app crashes on the device (at `setLockTaskPackages()`).

I suspect that the key is to find out why `getContext()` cannot be found and then hopefully everything else falls into place. Any idea what might be missing?

Comment: Where you are using `getContext()` ? Note: the  `getContext()` is used in fragment  to get context

Comment: I think the "this" answers may be right but cant verify at the moment as the app crashes, but I think the crashes are due to the app not being a device owner.   Trying to set that is giving me the following error which I am trying to follow up on in the Samsung forums:
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 2000 nor current process has com.samsung.android.knox.permission.KNOX_PROXY_ADMIN_INTERNAL.,com.sec.enterprise.permission.MDM_PROXY_ADMIN_INTERNAL

Answer (score 1):

If you're using activity use the keyword `this`, instead of `getContext`.

Answer (score 1):

`getContext()` is used in fragment to get context.Is this is Activity,You can use `Yourclass.this` or `this`. also you can get knowladge about what can you use for context using [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/mastering-android-context-7055c8478a22)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I will explain what the solution is. In Android official Documentations, in the line:

```
ComponentName adminName = getComponentName(context);
```

The `getComponentName()` is just a name similarity to the method of Activity.java.
The purpose of the document is to use `getComponentName(Context context)` in the class which extends `AdminReceiver`: (And you have to implement it)

```
class   AdminReceiver : DeviceAdminReceiver() {

    companion object {
        fun getComponentName(context: Context): ComponentName {
            return ComponentName(
                context,
                AdminReceiver::class.java
            )
        }

    }

}
```